# Return different objects using map without pushing into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, reduce, flatten

The following code in JavaScript:

```
const mixedObjects = [1,2,3].map(num => {
    return { a: 'always same' }
});
```

returns the following result:

```
[
  {a: 'always same'},
  {a: 'always same'},
  {a: 'always same'}
]
```

I want to return the following **without** declaring an empty array outside and then pushing into it. So do it all inside the map. Is this possible?

What I want to return:

```
[
  {a: 'always same'},
  {b: 1},
  {a: 'always same'},
  {b: 2},
  {a: 'always same'},
  {b: 3}
]
```

Comment: `[1,2,3].reduce((result, b) => [...result, { a: 'always same' }, { b }] , []);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.flatMap()`, and return a tuple of the 2 objects on each iteration. The flatMap would create a flattened array of objects.

```js
const mixedObjects = [1,2,3].flatMap(b => {
  return [{ a: 'always same' }, { b }]
});

console.log(mixedObjects);
```

Comment: excellent thank you, is flatMap new? Is it supported for modern browsers the same way if I was to do it using map and push into array?

Comment: It's relatively new (much newer than push), but it's support by all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `map` and `flat` methods:

```js
const mixedObjects = [1,2,3].map(num => {
    return [{ a: 'always same' }, {b: num}];
}).flat();
```

P. S. Or use `flatMap` method as suggested by Ori Drori.

Answer (score 0):

... [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based solutions work as well ...

```js
console.log(
  [1,2,3].reduce((result, b) =>
    [...result, { a: 'always same' }, { b }] , []
  )
);
console.log(
  [1,2,3].reduce((result, b) =>
    result.concat({ a: 'always same' }, { b }), []
  )
);
console.log(
  [1,2,3].reduce((result, b) => {
  
    result.push({ a: 'always same' }, { b });
    return result;

  }, [])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```